# Error : type object 'Inventory' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models

I created a model and used random generator for it. Thus, I had to use UserManager for that model. Wen I am using this model in views, I am getting the above error. I have done this multiple times and never got an error. I don't know what is wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance!

models

```
def unique_rand():
    while True:
        code = Inventory.objects.make_random_password(length=6, allowed_chars="1234567890")
        if not Inventory.objects.filter(code=code).exists():
            return code

class Inventory(models.Model):
    premises = models.ForeignKey(Premises, on_delete = None)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False,unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,default = unique_rand)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank=True)
    is_defected = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

views

```
   class Inventory(ListView):
       model = Inventory
       template_name = 'inventory.html'

       def get_queryset(self):
            pre = Premises.objects.get(userprofile__user = self.request.user)
            queryset = Inventory.objects.filter(premises = pre)
            return queryset
```

edit: here is the traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /operations/Inventory/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/urvi/qwenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 142, in get
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "/home/urvi/Desktop/atventus-work-spaces/operations/views.py", line 34, in get_queryset
queryset = Inventory.objects.filter(premises = pre)
AttributeError: type object 'Inventory' has no attribute 'objects'
[07/Aug/2019 18:28:06] "GET /operations/Inventory/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90758
[07/Aug/2019 18:28:06] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5670
```

I have already imported models and Usermanager.

Comment: add full error traceback

Comment: added it. Please check.

Comment: `objects = UserManager()` can you add `UserManager` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called your view the same name as the model. Rename the view.